# What is the magnitude of sum of complex exponentials?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I know that $\ |Ae^{ix}|=A$

But I couldn't find a way to formulise the magnitude of sum of N exponentials that is:

$|\sum_{n=0}^{N} e^{inx}|=? \ $where $\ N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$

I will appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say what your thoughts on this problem are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: use a geometric series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponential
may confuse you,
but,
if you let
$e^{ix} = r$,
then
$\sum_{n=0}^{N} e^{inx}
=\sum_{n=0}^{N} r^n$.

You should be able
to sum this
and then get its
absolute value.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.